# Good Linux podcasts/links for beginners

Tags: linux

There are quite a few out there, thats why I am asking for some recommendations. I am looking for some good linux podcasts/websites that are for beginners making the switch to using Linux as their primary OS.

I ve been encountering some basic doubts that were solved by googling, but it sure would be nice to know things in a structured fashion so that I know the generalities of the best-practices, gotchas etc and can figure out the specifics.

Answer (score 4):

Checkout theses very good podcasts from [JupiterBroadcasting](http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/) :

- [Linux Action Show](http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/?cat=4) : about new Linux stuff, interviews (Mark Shuttleworth, CrossOver's CEO, Linspire's CEO...) and more
- [In Depth Look](http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/?cat=153) : in depth on a specific topic, like VirtualBox or security tools
- [The Big Story & News Update](http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/?cat=154) : short podcast about news in the Linux world

They are very fun to listen, so enjoy !

Also, IBM provides good podcasts on the [IBM Linux Technology Center Podcast](http://planet-ltc.org/podcasts/).

You also asked for links, here's some that was useful for me :

- [How to fix the most common Linux problems](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/how-fix-most-common-linux-problems)
- [Learn 10 good UNIX usage habits](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-badunixhabits.html)

Answer (score 4):

FLOSS Weekly  http://www.twit.tv/FLOSS

They've had excellent guests and cover a lot of topics.

Answer (score 1):

[LugRadio](http://lugradio.org/) is pretty good if you like your podcasts with a British accent.

Comment: It's great, but they stopped making them nearly a year ago :(

Answer (score 1):

I really enjoy the [Ubuntu UK podcast](http://podcast.ubuntu-uk.org/).

Friendly folk.